# CodenameOne : Image reading issue

Tags: codenameone

I happen to receive images from my server, on client side, the image is received completely and saved in the Storage, (i check the size of the file in `.cn1` repository). but I can't display the image on a image viewer using :

```
Image img;           
img = Image.createImage(Storage.getInstance().createInputStream("00.png"));     

findImageViewer1().setImage(img);
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a corrupted or problematic image. I suggest you edit the question to discuss the way in which you download the image to storage which seems to be the source of the problem.

If you are using [ImageDownloadService](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/services/ImageDownloadService.html) then you should keep in mind that it **doesn't** create valid image files!

Comment: Its unclear what SZ does and the code is a bit inefficient. Try using Util.copy(inputStream,outputStream): https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/Util.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.io.OutputStream- verify that the resulting file is actually good. Try replacing the source in your servers.